# AFNetworking + big download files + resume downloads

Tags: download, afnetworking, resume

I need to download files > 500 Mo with AFNetworking.
Sometimes, the time to download them is > 10 minutes and if the app is in background, the download can't be complete.

So I want to try partial downloads. I found a lot of links and this seems to be possible with pause() and resume() methods on AFHTTPRequestOperation.

Actually, I did:

```
  [self.downloadOperation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{   
    // Clean up anything that needs to be handled if the request times out
    [self.downloadOperation pauseDownload];
  }];
```

DownloadOperation is a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperation (singleton).

And in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  // resume will only resume if it's paused...
  [[DownloadHTTPRequestOperation sharedOperation] resumeDownload];  
}
```

The server is OK to get the new range in headers...

My questions:

1) Is-t the good way to do it ?
2) Does the resume needs to change the outputStream (append:NO => append:YES) ? Or is-it managed somewhere by AFNetworking ? (don't find)

```
self.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:self.filePath append:YES];
```

Something like this (in DownloadHTTPRequestOperation):

```
- (void)pauseDownload
{
  NSLog(@"pause download");
  [self pause];
}

- (void)resumeDownload
{
  NSLog(@"resume download");
  self.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:self.filePath append:YES];
  [self resume];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Update:

As steipete may wont maintain AFDownloadRequestOperation any more (https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation/pull/68). NSURLSessionDownloadTask may be a better choice.

---

https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation

Also, I write a lib base on AFDownloadRequestOperation: https://github.com/BB9z/RFDownloadManager

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the old (non ARC) [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework for a similar task. *AllowResumeForFileDownloads* does what you need. Note that you server needs to support resuming by reading the *Range* http header.

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:downloadPath]){
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:downloadPath];
    [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tmpPath];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```