# Best practises for uploading video in ios app

Tags: ios, video, image-uploading

I'm developing an ios application.
As part of my application I need to support upload of a small sized video created by the user (20 mb).

What would be the best way to approach the uploading? Should I handle it with a queue? Are there any built in libraries that support it?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to upload videos to a server

Comment: Very constructive :) What if the user exists the application in middle, takes it to the background etc. etc. and I don't want to block interaction

Comment: What do you mean block interaction as in you want it to stop uploading the video or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the version of iOS you are planning to deploy on. As of iOS 7, the `NSURLSession` class provide mechanisms to allow you to finish larger file transfers in background and pause them.

Follow the next links for more information:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

**[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)** also provides very easy to use API around `NSURLSession` and it even supports older iOS versions (not their entire API though).

There is also some information in questions below:

- [How to work with large file uploads in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343053/how-to-work-with-large-file-uploads-in-ios)
- [AFNetworking + big download files + resume downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123288/afnetworking-big-download-files-resume-downloads)
- [How to Transfer Large Files over wifi in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829856/how-to-transfer-large-files-over-wifi-in-ios)

**If iOS7 support is enough for you, I would suggest using AFNetworking 2.0 library and following their best practices described in their extensive documentation at [CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/).**

If you do not want to use a library, go with Apple's built in class `NSURLSession`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called AFNetworking.[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
Learning how to implement look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445)
Here are some [examples](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example)